# How do you store aws access key and secret key in net core for production?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-lambda

I am working with IAmazonSqs, IAmazonLambda services.

I tried running app locally that uses above services for sqs and did dependency injection, but I got error saying `IAM credentials missing` something like that, so I realised I was missing profile locally with access key id and access secret. I will probably get same error once I publish this app on server? As I don’t have any profile file on server and manually linked patch in app settings json?

To access aws services on localhost, we create profile document (config or credential) which is then stored in `c:\users\{user}\.aws` in config or credentials files.

We put access key id and access secret key. That is good for localhost. But how do we set up net core app properly when we want to publish this into production? For instance build in teamcity and deploy via octopus? I think having those in `appsettings.json` is not good, and it should be kept in SDK store? App is hosted in aws itself.

I can't find any documentation on how to do this properly? In Microsoft Azure you access it via azure key vault, but what about in amazon aws?

Comment: [AWS Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager)

Comment: There is a secrets manager in AWS https://medium.com/@jonvines/using-aws-secrets-manager-with-dotnet-core-a44b54bba8d4

Comment: Parameter Store SecretString is yet other option.

Comment: What is 'production' in this case? If it's an AWS compute service such as EC2, ECS, or Lambda, then you launch the compute with an IAM role and the compute gets temporary, auto-rotated credentials via the IAM role.

Comment: You don't need any credentials, and you can't use secret manager (how would you have the permission to get the credentials?). You assign permission directly to your Lambda using AWS IAM https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-permissions.html

Comment: But wouldn’t I get error that credentials are missing if I don’t have those credentials or is picking the region enough for net core app since it will be hosted in same aws anyway? See the problem is that when I was testing locally and I forgot to make a profile with aws explorer i got and error saying `iam credentials missing ` something like that, so when moving this from local to production it either picks up the region but in production where do I put my access key if and access secret key in which file or do I not need to do that as it’s in same aws anyway and it only looks région?